# Python .sort() on a list of a set returns None

Tags: python, sorting, set, union

Python 3.6

Just had this issue (below), where adding `.sort()` caused my expression to return None.

Should this work? if not why not?

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,3,45,5,6,6,7,7]
>>> y = [3,4,34,643,6,234,3,34,5,22,3]
>>> w =[x,y]
>>> x = [set(i) for i in w]
>>> x
[{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 45}, {34, 3, 4, 643, 6, 5, 234, 22}]
>>> common_elements = list(set.union(*x))
>>> common_elements
[1, 2, 3, 34, 5, 6, 7, 4, 643, 234, 45, 22]
>>> common_elements = list(set.union(*x)).sort() #Adding .sort() returns None
>>> common_elements
>>>                #Nothing, None
```

Comment: Sorry mate, it was so quick, I couldn't tell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `list.sort` method sorts the list in place and returns `None`. If you want to return the sorted list use `sorted` method.

```
>>> lst=[5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst=[5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
>>> lst=sorted(lst)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

So you will have to use: `common_elements = sorted(list(set.union(*x)))` or you can sort in place like this:

```
common_elements = list(set.union(*x))
common_elements.sort()
```

Comment: Seems obvious, when you say it like that. I thought it would return the sorted list... after sorting it in place. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesSchinner Note that builtin function `sorted()` does indeed return a new list.

Comment: I realize, my understanding of 'inplace' wasn't quite right. I seemed to think it meant 'sort the data in the same memory location as that data' but a better explanation would be 'sort the data in the same memory location as that data and return None'

Answer (score 1):

`sort` is inplace. It does the sort and does not return a value.

```
l = list((4,3,2,1))
l
# OUTPUT
# [4, 3, 2, 1]
l.sort()
l
# OUTPUT
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the sorted method for sets:

```
common_elements = list(sorted(set.union(*x)))
```

sort method is inplace, it wont return anything, the other opcion is

```
common_elements = list(set.union(*x))
common_elements.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reassign common_elements when you call .sort(). .sort() modifies the list in-place and returns None.